# extending extended class or how to get code out of BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

since one cannot extend an extension of a class such as `class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState>`, what is a cleanest way to get some functions out of my bloc file? Since the logic is a bit more complex, I would like to get some sub functions out like in

```dart
@override
Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
  yield* event.map(
    loadRequested: (e) => _mapLoadRequestedToState(),
    dataEntered: (e) => _mapDataEnteredToState(),
  );
}

Stream<LogicChainState> _mapLoadRequestedToState() async* {
  final dataRaw = loadData();
  final dataProc = initData(dataRaw);
  yield doSomeMore(dataProc);
}
```

I don't like the idea of using global functions. I could create a class

```dart
class MyBlocUtils {
  MyData initData(MyData dataRaw) {
  ...
  }
  MyData doSomeMore(MyData dataProc) {
  ...
  }    
}
```

which still isn't as nice as using a function defined within the class `MyBloc`.

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you want to move them from the bloc class to another class?

Comment: just to make the code a bit more clean. Keep the main structure within the bloc class file and move some utility functions to some utility files. Currently I am scrolling quite a bit in the bloc file

Comment: Have you tried exporting your code to a mixin? Tutorial here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to separate your methods into multiple files, but keep them in the same class, you could use [`extension`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) methods.

**my_bloc.dart**

```dart
part 'my_bloc_utils.dart';

class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  Stream<LogicChainState> _mapLoadRequestedToState() async* {
    final dataRaw = loadData();
    final dataProc = initData(dataRaw);
    yield doSomeMore(dataProc);
  }
}
```

**my_bloc_utils.dart**

```dart
part of 'my_bloc.dart';

extension MyBlocUtils on MyBloc {
  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    yield* event.map(
      loadRequested: (e) => _mapLoadRequestedToState(),
      dataEntered: (e) => _mapDataEnteredToState(),
    );
  }
}
```

You can access the methods in just the same way as you keep everything in a single file:

```dart
import 'my_bloc.dart';

final myBloc = MyBloc();
final stream = myBloc.mapEventToState(MyEvent());
```

Comment: very interesting idea, but I think this does not allow the way I would like for splitting the class. My aim is to make the logic a bit more clear and to speed-up finding the code. Thus I would want to keep mapEventToState with alle the _mapLoadRequestedToState  etc in the bloc main class and to move the helpers loadData, initData etc. to a or some utilities files

Comment: Maybe you should consider restructuring your bloc class. Splitting your bloc to multiple blocs would be the answer of your question.